# Проверить поставлен ли лайк, если нет изменить параметры запроса. API ВКонтакте

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Привет, помогите с `API` в ВКонтакте

Спомощью `API` узнаю `ID` пользователя и заношу его в перемменную `$user_uid`
Далее вибераю с базы данных всех пользователей кроме `$user_uid`

```
$result_link_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vk_likes WHERE order_user_uid!='$user_uid'");
$myrow_link_check = mysql_fetch_array($result_link_check);
```

Потом проверяю есть ли лайк от пользователя `$user_uid`

```
$response_pr = file_get_contents("http://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=".$myrow_link_check["type"]."&owner_id=".$myrow_link_check["owner_id"]."&item_id=".$myrow_link_check["item_id"]."&filter=likes");
$resp_pr = json_decode($response_pr, true);
if (!in_array($user_uid, $resp_pr['response']['users'])) 
{
echo "Найден лайк";
break;
}
else
{
echo "Лайк не найден";  
}
```

Проблема в следующем, если лайк не найден нужно произвести всю операцию заново но только взять уже следующие параметры `$myrow_link_check["owner_id"]` и `$myrow_link_check["item_id"]`

Подскажите хоть в какую сторну рить

Comment: Можно узнать какова цель сей хитрой манипуляции? Что-то мне кажется есть более простой путь решения задачи, чем вы сейчас мудрите

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Хочу сделать вход на сайт через лайк, в форму человек вставляет ссылку на свой профиль в вконтакте с его ссылки я получаю его ид и дальше даю ему ссылку по которой он должен поставить свой лайк, потом проверяю если лайк поставлен значит это его страница и авторизирую его.